# Unable to run migration scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-5, rake, ubuntu-18.04

I've been creating an app using Ruby on Rails on Windows for almost two years and I've had it. This weekend I started migrating my dev environment over to Ubuntu because it can run some tools/services not available in Windows.

I tried to run a migration and I got this error msg:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate

rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:

  class AddAttachmentImportCsvFileToTabClientProjectCommunities < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
/home/joe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:525:in `inherited'
/home/joe/workspace/asb_base/db/migrate/20170829235908_add_attachment_import_csv_file_to_tab_client_project_communities.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

First I tried the suggestion from the error msg and explicitly declared Rails version in the migration script. I used `ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]` since that was what was in the error msg, and then I tried `ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]` since that was the version of Rails the migration was originally written with; neither one worked in Ubuntu.

I thought maybe it was because the version of RoR I had on Ubuntu (Ruby 2.5.1/Rails 5.2.0) was different than that on Windows (v2.3.3/v5.1.4). I explicitly locked my RoR versions to use what I had in Windows and then ran the migration - still the same error msg.

What I don't understand is why rake thinks the migration script in question was written using Rails v4.x. Even the earliest source code I wrote (even before this one particular) was using Rails v5.x. Googling isn't giving me any solid, usable answers - has anyone solved this before?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `rake db:migrate:reset` (only do this in development!)

> "What I don't understand is why rake thinks the migration script in
>   question was written using Rails v4.x?"

It doesn't. The version (4.2) is hardcoded as an example in the error message.

From activerecord source....

```
def self.inherited(subclass) # :nodoc:
  super
  if subclass.superclass == Migration
    raise StandardError, "Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. " \
      "Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:\n" \
      "\n" \
      "  class #{subclass} < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]"
  end
end
```

Comment: I ran `rails db:migrate:reset` and got `Environment data not found in the schema. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development`. Then I ran that new command and got `rails aborted! Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate:set' (see --tasks)`.

Comment: Just to clarify...you get `Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate:set' (see --tasks)` when you run `bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development`? If not and you are running `rails db:migrate:set`....`it should be rails db:migrate:reset`

Answer (score 0):

You say that you've "tried to run a migration" but note that the command you ran:

`$ bundle exec rake db:migrate`

will run not just one migration, but ALL migrations that are currently down (aka have not been run yet for this environment). It is likely that, because you are migrating for the first time on Ubuntu, this command is trying to run every one of your migrations. Migrations that worked in the past without inheriting from an explicit version will not work this time around if you've upgraded Rails to 5.1 or later since they were run.

Make sure that you are updating *every* migration file with `ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]` (or whatever the correct version is), if they all need to be re-run. And if you ever do want to migrate just a single migration, the command is: `bundle exec rake db:migrate:up VERSION=XXXXXXXX`, where `XXXXXXXX` is the timestamp at the beginning of the relevant migration file.

Also note that this is why it is not recommended that databases get rebuilt from migration files. [Here is a blog on that topic](https://www.madetech.com/blog/migrations-seeds-and-pipelines).

Comment: I thought the same thing but if the migrations were working in Rails version 5.1.x, shouldn't they still work in Rails 5.2? I thought that was the whole purpose of versioning the migrations?